# How to stop showing screen recording permission promt if there is no option for don't ask again

Tags: android, screenshot, android-permissions

While developing screen recording application I don't want user to show screen recording promt after taking its permission one time.(by check on don't ask again will do that) but some device don't provide don't ask again option in that case how can I achive my desired result. Is there any setting to where I can redirect user to do it.

for clarifying problem attaching images of screen recording promt.
[There is no option for don't ask again so User have to face this dialog everytime. device redmi note 5a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj86l.png)

[If user checked don't ask again then do have to go through this dialog again. I have no problem with this kind of dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XIQr.png)

I want to redirect user to setting by which dialog don't pop up again.

Comment: Please provide your code, along with error and your expected result

See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: hello thanks for commenting , there is no error , code working fine, problem lies with devices which don't have don't ask again option.I edit question for better clarification.

Comment: I need the same, did you find a way to stop the prompt being shown every time the screen is recorded?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only way to fix it is probably tricking the system into thinking the screen capturing didn't stop that way only on starting application the permission is required to be given. As if the capture was only paused not fully stopped.